# PHP $_SESSION value differs on www

Tags: php

I have a website. People can login it on here

```
sub.domain.com
```

If they login here, the session will do its job and user will be logged in. On any page at sub.domain.com, the session value be will returned so it will work fine.

But site can also be reached from www.sub.domain.com . When user logins at sub.domain.com, the session value is empty at www.sub.domain.com.
I mean if user logs in at sub.domain.com,
When he navigates to www.sub.domain.com, site will say 'please login', but user was already logged in at site without 'www'.
Hope it was all clear, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add in your main script at the top, **before session_start**.

```
 ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.domain.com' );
```

If you running PHP with suhosin enabled, try disabling there settings too

```
  ini_set("suhosin.session.cryptdocroot", "Off");
  ini_set("suhosin.cookie.cryptdocroot", "Off");
```

Source [PHP bug tracker](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43682)

Thanks to @RandomDave

> You could dynamically determine the domain from $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] so you don't have to hard-code the domain name

```
  ini_set('session.cookie_domain', strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 4)) == 'www.' ? substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 3) : '.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
```

Comment: +1 this is the best way, for whatever reason I have found that `ini_set()` works better than `session_set_cookie_params()`. Two salient points you don't mention in your answer through: This *must* be called *before* `session_start()`, and you could dynamically determine the domain from `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` so you don't have to hard-code the domain name, something like `ini_set('session.cookie_domain', strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 4)) == 'www.' ? substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 3) : '.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );`

Answer (score 0):

Set the cookie_domain for your session.

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.domain.com' );
```

Or change this setting in your `php.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Sessions use cookies to store the session identifier, if you're browsing over `www.` that is where the cookie will be set.

You can alleviate this issue by setting the session cookie domain prefixed with a dot, which will act essentially as a wildcard for `*.domain.com` by using `.domain.com`. You do this with `session_set_cookie_params` like so:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com');
```

A safer example would use `session_get_cookie_params` and re-pass the other values back in. Even better, you could modify the `php.ini` on your server to set `session.cookie_domain` value to be `.domain.com` (you could also use `ini_set` for this).

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a `.htaccess` at the root of your site like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sub.domain.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
```